# How to re-format a matrix

Tags: command-line, text-formatting

I have a file like this:

```
column1   column2   column3  column4   column5
 5e-05   1e-05 0.00083   4e-05 0.00021
 6e-05   3e-05 1.00083   2e-05 1.00021
```

And I need to re-format it to print and output like this.

```
column1   5e-05      6e-05
column2   1e-05      3e-05
column3   0.00083    1.00083
column4   4e-05      2e-05
column5   0.00021    1.00021
```

I was trying using

```
 tr ' ' '\n' | 
 pr -3t
```

but with no success until now.

I find a solution :

```
awk '
{ 
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)  {
        a[NR,i] = $i
    }
}
NF>p { p = NF }
END {    
    for(j=1; j<=p; j++) {
        str=a[1,j]
        for(i=2; i<=NR; i++){
            str=str" "a[i,j];
        } 
        print str 

      }
 }' file
```

but the output looks like this:

```
column1 5e-05 5e-05
column2 1e-05 1e-05
column3 0.00083 0.00083
column4 4e-05 4e-05
column5 0.00021 0.00021
```

And I want that the numbers of the output are formatted

Comment: If you search *transpose* you will see this has been pretty well covered here before

Comment: There are several answers with scripts, but i cannot not mention how great [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/manual/html_node/Reverse-and-Transpose.html#Reverse-and-Transpose) is for this purpose.  `datamash` is around for not very long, and several answers do not mention it.

Comment: Tuck on `egrep -v '^$' |` to the first line, to exclude the blank lines made by `tr`.

Comment: ... or if your version of `tr` supports the `-s` (squeeze) flag, `tr -s ' ' '\n' < yourfile | pr -3t`

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean by "one row up the column" - I appear to get exactly the desired output from your posted input. Does your input have a mix of spaces and tabs? if so, you may need to replace `tr -s ' ' '\n'` with `tr -s '[:space:]' '\n'`

Comment: Sorry @steeldriver, but your solution work very well , I make a mistake. Please not consider my previous comments, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found two answers to the problem proposed:

The first one propose by @steeldriver:

```
    tr -s ' ' '\n' < file | pr -3t
```

And the second one, I found in another discussionabout transpose matrix elements:

```
awk '
{ 
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)  {
        a[NR,i] = $i
    }
}
 NF>p { p = NF }
END {    
     for(j=1; j<=p; j++) {
          str=a[1,j]
    for(i=2; i<=NR; i++){
        str=str" "a[i,j];
    } 
    print str 

  }
 }' file
```